# How to store firestore collection reference and add as field for different collection in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, redux

[like shown in pic the id is from blogs collection document id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NVFx.png)[with rich text editor I am setting my blogDetails collection so my question is that when I post bloDetails I want two field one is blog which I am getting fine and second is blogID field which will be like (blogID:/blogs/blogs collection id) this blog collection id will come from blogs collection id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUbyv.png)

I have collection of blogs and also a collection of *blogDetails*. I want to set blogs collection, document Id as reference data type field in *blogDetails* collection document's field and I want to do it when I add *blogDetails* to firestore,

here is the code for adding *blogDetails*, I want to add *blogID* something like this,

`(blogID:/blogs/(blogs_document-id)`

Please help. Thank you.

```
    export const setBlogDetails = (blog) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            firestore.collection("blogDetails").add({
                ...{ blog },}).then(() => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: ADD_BLOG_DETAILS,
                        blog
                     });
                }).catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
            });
        };
    }
```

Here is code for setting blogs collection:

```
    export const setBlog = (blogData) => {
        return (dispatch) => 
        {
            firestore.collection("blogs").add({
                ...blogData,
                }).then(() => {
                dispatch({
                    type: ADD_BLOG,
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two operations like this: (I assume you want to store an Id of blog details in the Blogs Table)

```
setBlogDetails = (blog) => { 
        return (dispatch) => { 
            firestore.collection("blogs")
                 .add({ ...{ blog },})
                 .then((docRef) => { 
                       // docRef reference to the newly created blog.
                       dispatch({ type: ADD_BLOG_DETAILS, blog });
                       return firestore.collection("blogsDetails").add({...blog, blogRef: docRef.id});
                   })
                 .then(() => {
                      dispatch({
                      type: ADD_BLOG,
                  });
                 .catch((err) => { console.log(err); }); }; 
        }
```

Comment: I want to store id of blogs collection inside blogDetails field as reference  so when I click on blog card it will show some information from blogs collection and some information from blogDetails collection thank you

Comment: I have edited my answer. You want to save in blogs table first and save the reference in Blog Details

Comment: I only want to set blogDetails when I run setBlogDetails function I do not want to set blogs collection, for setting blogs collection  I have different function set up which is setBlog methode which code I have provided above, Both methode is getting different data as a parameter

Comment: For that , I think you can store the docRef in your store (if you use redux) and get it from store when you need it. You can also use localStorage if you dont use redux.

Comment: That is my question that how should i store the reference and whenever I set blogDetails it goes to blogDetails collection as field for every blogs collection document , I am using redux for state management

Comment: and It should be reference data type not a string data type